# Error while opening Terminal and bash terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

whenever i open my terminal  i get this error, hope this is due to unfinished installation of virtual environment. please help me to remove it. Whenever i open my bash terminal , i get the same error message[This is the error message of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeIIG.png), how to solve it?

I tried to remove the unfinished installation of virtual environment but unable to find the solution.[This is the error in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmx4K.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. This makes it easier for more people to find and read your question. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: The call to the script probably still resides in your bash startup files. What does `grep virtualenvwrapper ~/.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile` say?

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall virtualenvwrapper package to ignore this error message. Try the following command to install virtualenvwrapper.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Source : https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: it says that virtualenwrapper is already instaled